# Looking for add-ons

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm new of vaadin and of its add-ons. Now I have to do a panel like this:

[image]

but I shouldn't want to use four, five ... vaadin Upload component because in this way is difficult to manage. I saw some add-ons like easyupload, but I don't know if these are able to manage my situation.

My situation is the following:

I have to upload some file, for each of them I have to assign a label(Patent,Tax code,Agreement etc) and finally I have to persist them in a datsabase.

Now I want to ask you if there is an smart way or an add-on than helps me in this situation?

Comment: Easyupload does not allow you to "label" the uploaded files before the upload, instead you can upload many files in one go, even via Drag&Drop. But you could show the uploaded files in a list and then put a textfield beside euch of the uploaded files and then persist them in the DB.
Or just add another button with "Add more files" and then just generate a new line in your upload form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there aren't.

[Easy Uploads](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/easyuploads) is just to simplify the upload adding multi files upload, drag and drop upload and loading bar.

[Multi File Upload](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/multifileupload) is just for manage multi upload and queue of files upload.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MultiFileUpload addon:
https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/multifileupload